# Where can I find good 2D-code library for Java ME?

Tags: java, java-me, barcode, decode

Do you know any good library for Java ME?

Application from http://www.i-nigma.com/ works very well, but there is not too much information on this website.

Of course I found http://qrcode.sourceforge.jp/ but compared to above its really mediocre.

I need this library to read 2D-code and then decrypt cipher. Library can be commercial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) has a (slightly old) J2ME implementation, but one that should still work just fine. It is free and open source.

See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/javame

Answer (score 0):

i-nigma's contact page is at http://www.i-nigma.com/ContactUs.html